# Jobs page has unexpected behavior on pager when city is "pasadena"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I live in **Pasadena, MD** and was searching for jobs near my area. There appear to be at least two pages of results:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=Pasadena%2C+MD&d=20&u=Miles

When selecting page two at the bottom the search criteria is changed to jobs in **Pasadena, CA**: 
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-pasadena?sort=i&pg=2

When you navigate 'back' to the previous page, the search criteria is changed to Pasadena, CA.

I also noticed that the link itself is correct but there seems to be some sort of redirect happening when you click it:

```
<a class="job-link" href="/jobs?sort=i&amp;l=Pasadena%2c+md&amp;d=20&amp;u=Miles&amp;pg=2" title="page 2 of 2">2</a>
```

**STR**

- Search "Pasadena, MD" in the location
- Scroll down to the pager and select page 2
- Notice you are on page 2 of Pasadena, CA results.

**EDIT**

It appears as though even clicking the links here is redirecting to the `developer-jobs-in-pasadena` url.

Answer (score 6):

We had a bug that treated all the `Pasadena`s as `Pasadena, CA`... all the `Birmingham`s as `Birmingham, UK`. What's even funnier is that... the urls weren't sticky (so while today `/developer-jobs-in-pasadena` would point to `Pasadena, CA` that could change in the future).

I've just deployed a fix for this. If you see more issues while using our job board... you know where to find us :)

Thanks for reporting this!